# How to get this Facial Rigging? see attached image

Tags: rigging

I saw this youtube video on facial rigging that did such a wonderful job. However I don't know if it's based on an add-on or some advanced amature rigging. Please let me know either way. Thanks in advance!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfL8VD7vGGs

[image]